# What happens to bullets that hit the T-1000?

Tags: terminator-2-judgment-day, the-terminator-series

When the T-1000 is hit with bullets, as shown in various *Terminator 2* scenes, what happens to the bullets? Do they remain within the terminator's mass? Or do they exit?

Comment: You'll have better luck asking one question per post. Secondary questions that wander off on a tangent should be submitted separately.

Comment: The ideas are sort of related. Both questions are asking about a foreign body that is introduced to the T-1000.

Comment: +1 for tidying it up to the internal foreign bodies.

Comment: I always assumed that the T-1000 Terminator just ejects them out of the back when he gets a spare moment.

Comment: Ah yes, just like Dave from _Meet Dave_ ejects the hot dogs from the hot dog eating contest out of his back.

Comment: I could've sworn they were expelled and that there's a scene in T2 showing that, but I can't find it and may have well imagined it.

Comment: @SQB - I've been hunting for any scenes that show evidence of the bullets after they've been fired. I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: @Richard Brilliant pun!

Answer (score 8):

A conversation between Sarah and the Terminator in the [Terminator 2 novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(Frakes_novel)) by Randall Frakes indicates that the bullets pass *through* the T-1000.

> [Sarah] : *“This T-1000...**what happens when you shoot it**?”*
>
> [Terminator] : *“Ballistic penetration hydrostatically shocks it, but only for a few
>   seconds. **Based on recent observation, it can liquefy its molecular
>   structure to allow bullets to pass through**"*

---

The [shooting script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/t2.txt) had a modified version of the lines above...

> **SARAH :** *This T-1000... what happens when you shoot it?*
>
> **TERMINATOR :** *Ballistic penetration shocks it, but only for a few
>   seconds.*

...but these don't appear in the film, presumably because the line is essentially redundant.

In the film, we see several visible exit wounds. This would tie in nicely with the suggestion that the T-1000 is capable of simply allowing the bullet to exit in a smooth through-and-through track.

[image]

The total lack of any visible fragments when the T-1000 is frozen and then destroyed would strongly suggests that the T-1000 simply disposes of any remaining bullets (or other foreign bodies such as shotgun pellets) by ejecting them at a convenient moment.

Comment: But how would the T-1000 even be able to control holding onto bullets when it is frozen? The behavior would be different if it were actually room temp than if it was frozen solid. 

It's like freezing a human and then shooting them and saying that the bullet would have stuck, when in reality, hardening something would have a totally different effect.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar - In its frozen form, I'd expect the bullet to travel through the T2

Answer (score 3):

Projectiles either penetrate and exit, or cause an impact creator and simply fall lose. None of the footage shows dark passageways leading inside the T-1000. I doubt the bullets are stuck in there. The 'wound' would of had to close somewhat around the bullet to leave that nice shiny spot in the middle. Apparently, shotgun slugs exit while 9mm ricochet. Hypothetically sometimes they get stuck, presumably to be pushed back out when it repairs the wound.

1:05, while escaping Pescadero.

[image]

[image]

Eariler in the sceen from the mall hallway, they do not penatrate.

[image]

Later at the steel mill, they have even more effect.

[image]